# Python data structure sort list alphabetically

Tags: python, list, sorting, alphabetical

I am a bit confused regarding data structure in python; `()`,`[]`, and `{}`. I am trying to sort a simple list, probably since I cannot identify the type of data I am failing to sort it.

My list is simple: `['Stem', 'constitute', 'Sedge', 'Eflux', 'Whim', 'Intrigue']`

My question is what type of data this is, and how to sort the words alphabetically?

Comment: If you want to sort your list then you can use "list=['Stem', 'constitute', 'Sedge', 'Eflux', 'Whim', 'Intrigue'] 
list.sort() 
print list" .

Comment: `[]` encloses the builtin datatype `list`, (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). Lists are just groups of values (they can contain other iterable objects- i.e nested lists).
`()` encloses the builtin `tuple`. They are immutable (cannot be changed). (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).
And `{}` encloses the builtin `dictionary`. Parallels with a dictionary (for words), where a 'key' would be the word and the 'value's is the definition. (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm).

Answer (score 326, accepted):

`[]` denotes a [list](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), `()` denotes a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and `{}` denotes a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You should take a look at the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) as these are the very basics of programming in Python.

What you have is a list of strings. You can sort it like this:

```
In [1]: lst = ['Stem', 'constitute', 'Sedge', 'Eflux', 'Whim', 'Intrigue']

In [2]: sorted(lst)
Out[2]: ['Eflux', 'Intrigue', 'Sedge', 'Stem', 'Whim', 'constitute']
```

As you can see, words that start with an uppercase letter get preference over those starting with a lowercase letter. If you want to sort them independently, do this:

```
In [4]: sorted(lst, key=str.lower)
Out[4]: ['constitute', 'Eflux', 'Intrigue', 'Sedge', 'Stem', 'Whim']
```

You can also sort the list in reverse order by doing this:

```
In [12]: sorted(lst, reverse=True)
Out[12]: ['constitute', 'Whim', 'Stem', 'Sedge', 'Intrigue', 'Eflux']

In [13]: sorted(lst, key=str.lower, reverse=True)
Out[13]: ['Whim', 'Stem', 'Sedge', 'Intrigue', 'Eflux', 'constitute']
```

**Please note:** If you work with Python 3, then `str` is the correct data type for every string that contains human-readable text. However, if you still need to work with Python 2, then you might deal with unicode strings which have the data type `unicode` in Python 2, and not `str`. In such a case, if you have a list of unicode strings, you must write `key=unicode.lower` instead of `key=str.lower`.

Comment: Using the second example on a pymongo `find_one()` result from a MongoDB database, I get error:  `descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'`.  The result is an array of strings and implemented like this:  `results['keywords'] = sorted(keywords['keywords'], key=str.lower)`.  Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: @user1063287 Sorry for my late response. In your case, you need to write `key=unicode.lower` instead of `key=str.lower`. This is because you are dealing with unicode strings, not byte strings. Please refer to the official [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) for further information on this, especially for the respective differences between Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 42):

Python has a built-in function called [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), which will give you a sorted list from any iterable you feed it (such as a list (`[1,2,3]`); a dict (`{1:2,3:4}`), although it will just return a sorted list of the keys; a set (`{1,2,3,4`); or a tuple (`(1,2,3,4)`)).

```
>>> x = [3,2,1]
>>> sorted(x)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x
[3, 2, 1]
```

Lists also have a [`sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) method that will perform the sort in-place (x.sort() returns None but changes the x object) .

```
>>> x = [3,2,1]
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Both also take a `key` argument, which should be a callable (function/lambda) you can use to change what to sort by.
For example, to get a list of `(key,value)`-pairs from a dict which is sorted by value you can use the following code:

```
>>> x = {3:2,2:1,1:5}
>>> sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])  # Items returns a list of `(key,value)`-pairs
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 5)]
```

Answer (score 18):

You're dealing with a python list, and sorting it is as easy as doing this.

```
my_list = ['Stem', 'constitute', 'Sedge', 'Eflux', 'Whim', 'Intrigue']
my_list.sort()
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use built-in `sorted` function.

```
print sorted(['Stem', 'constitute', 'Sedge', 'Eflux', 'Whim', 'Intrigue'])
```

Answer (score 5):

`ListName.sort()` will sort it alphabetically. You can add `reverse=False/True` in the brackets to reverse the order of items: `ListName.sort(reverse=False)`

Comment: Is this a comment for Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = ()
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> a = []
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> a = {}
>>> type(a)
<type 'dict'>
>>> a =  ['Stem', 'constitute', 'Sedge', 'Eflux', 'Whim', 'Intrigue'] 
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['Eflux', 'Intrigue', 'Sedge', 'Stem', 'Whim', 'constitute']
>>>
```