# Flatten a list of strings to characters and then de-dupe the new list

Tags: python

I have the following and have flattened the list via [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
>>> letterlist = [lt for wd in wordlist for lt in wd]
>>> print(letterlist)
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

Can the list comprehension be extended to remove duplicate characters. The desired result is the following (in any order):

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'o', 'r', 't']
```

**I can convert to a set and then back to a list but I'd prefer to keep it as a list.**

Comment: `letterlist = set([lt for wd in wordlist for lt in wd])`

Comment: Do you have to convert it back to a list? What functionality do you lose from having it as a set?

Comment: This isn't hard to find: [eliminate dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7961390), [sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14032557)

Comment: @sweeneyrod thanks - is it possible without changing collection type? i.e. can the comprehension be amended to answer the question

Comment: @whytheq I don't understand what you mean. Like the answers below say, you could change the square brackets to curly ones and make it a set comprehension (and therefore a set), but I presumed (from "I'd prefer to keep it as a list.") that you had some reason not to use a set.

Comment: @plg fair comment - although my question is not in connection with sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to use a set comprehension instead of a list comp:

```
letterlist = {lt for wd in wordlist for lt in wd}
```

All I did was replace the square brackets with curly braces. This works in Python 2.7 and up.

For Python 2.6 and earlier, you'd use the `set()` callable with a generator expression instead:

```
letterlist = set(lt for wd in wordlist for lt in wd)
```

Last, but not least, you can replace the comprehension syntax altogether by producing the letters from all sequences by *chaining* the strings together, treat them all like one long sequence, with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable); you give that a sequence of sequences and it'll give you back one long sequence:

```
from itertools import chain
letterlist = set(chain.from_iterable(wordlist))
```

Comment: cheers Martijn - see the last line of my OP - looks like I was already onto the best approach!

Comment: what is the difference between your and my answer?

Comment: @oleg: Mine didn't start with just the sentence 'I think you need to use a set comprehension'. That was **not** an answer until you edited it.

Comment: @oleg: I also explain what the syntax difference is, and give more options.

Comment: just wanted to understand the reason for this "Gosh darn, really?". sorry.

Comment: @oleg That was in response to you giving an answer which was only one short sentence, which by itself was not suitable as an answer, and would have been better as a comment. Now that you have edited it, it is fine.

Comment: ...apparently I can use a dict, within the list compehension, as a way to only save the unique items.

Comment: @whytheq: you could, but that's just a set with values associated.

Comment: @whytheq: or do you mean to maintain the order of the unique elements? In that case I'd use a separate set to track what has been seen and use a list comprehension. See [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/480214)

Answer (score 3):

Sets are an easy way to get unique elements from an iterable. To flatten a list of lists, `itertools.chain` provides a handy way to do that.

```
from itertools import chain

>>> set(chain.from_iterable(['cat','dog','rabbit'])
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'o', 'r', 't'}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the interesting option...I'm new to Python so suspect that itertools is well worth me checking out

Answer (score 2):

I think set comprehension should be used

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letterlist = {lt for wd in wordlist for lt in wd}
print(letterlist)
```

this will work only in python 2.7 and higher
for previous versions use `set` instead of `{}`

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letterlist = set(lt for wd in wordlist for lt in wd)
print(letterlist)
```

Comment: @whytheq: This answer started with **just** *I think set comprehension should be used*. That was.. obvious to most visiting here, but without the later edit it wasn't an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... I saw the original one-liner but oleg has filled in the gaps. +1 oleg for filling in the gaps

Comment: thank You. sorry for one line answer. will try to give expanded answers next time