# Sort a list with certain values staying in constant positions

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of strings.  I want to only sort values that meet a certain condition. Consider this list

```
['foo','bar','testa','python','java','abc']
```

and I only want to sort the values with an `a` in them. The result should look like this

```
['foo','abc','bar','python','java','testa']
```

The elements with `a` will change places appropriately, but the other elements retain their original positions.

I have absolutely no idea how to implement this, so I hope someone else does. Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
y = sorted(w for w in x if 'a' in w)  # pick and sort only the elements with 'a'
x = [w if 'a' not in w else y.pop(0) for w in x]
```

The last line leaves word without an `'a'` in them unchanged, while those with `'a'` are picked progressively from the y list (that is already sorted)

**EDIT**:
@MartijnPieters solution performs better, since it uses an iterator and won't use additional memory to store `y`.

```
y = iter(sorted(w for w in x if 'a' in w))  # create iterator, don't use memory
x = [w if 'a' not in w else next(y) for w in x]  # yield from iter instead of popping from a list
```

Since it looks like you need this algorithm to work with different condition, you could put this into a method:

```
x = ['foo','bar','testa','python','java','abc']

def conditional_sort(ls, f):
    y = iter(sorted(w for w in ls if f(w)))
    return [w if not f(w) else next(y) for w in ls]

conditional_sort(x, lambda w: 'a' in w)
```

The first parameter would be the list, the second one a function that takes a single parameter and returns a `bool` value.

Comment: `sorted()` already returns a list, your `list()` call is redundant. It'd be more efficient if you used an iterator instead (`y = iter(sorted(...))` and `else next(y)`).

Comment: You may want to explain *what this does*. It works, but without an explanation it is not nearly as helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes fixed that. You are right on the iterator.

Comment: Also consider how this looks to a beginning programmer.  :-)

Comment: @Prune Sure, I was going to post my solution and then add the explanation after that (I see this is pretty common on SO). Could anybody please explain the downvote?

Comment: I don't know why this has a downvote, this is quite helpful. +1 Also, shouldn't the second line end with `for w in y`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing no, since `y` does not contain all the words if you iterate over the second list you'd lose elements. So you need to iterate over the list with all the elements (`x`) and pop from `y` if it meets the condition.

Comment: @Bit: I think the down-vote came against your original answer, which was only two lines of code and no explanation.  I know it was already there when I saw your first update per Martijn's comment.

Comment: @Prune I guess your right. I thought it was accepted on SO to post a draft of the solution first and then edit with the explanation, I'll post refined answers in the future

Comment: It is acceptable ... but this is a large community, and not everyone has learned all the guidelines.  I'm still picking up pointers.  My recommendation: keep up the good work, and don't sweat the occasional down-vote.  The one you just got is barely 1% of your total, and the overall response (currently +3/-1) suggests that you're on the right track.

Comment: @Prune I'll do that! I would just prefer sometimes to have some feedback from the downvoter so I can improve my answer. I guess some downvotes will just come anyways, so you're right that it is better to just move on and focus on improving the content I post. Thanks again for your words and your time.

Answer (score 1):

Find the elements with `a`; mark the positions and pull them out.

```
orig = ['foo','bar','testa','python','java','abc']
just_a = [str for str in orig if `a` in str]
mark = [`a` in str for str in orig]
```

This gives us

```
just_a = ['bar', 'testa', 'java', 'abc'] 
mark = [False, True, True, False, True, True]
```

Sort just_a; I'm sure you can do that.  Now, build your result: where there's `True` in `mark`, take the next item in the sorted list; otherwise, take the original element.

```
result = []
for pos in range len(orig):
    if mark[pos]:
        result.append(sort_a.pop())
    else:
        result.append(orig[pos])
```

This can be done with much less code.  Among other things, this last loop can be done with a list comprehension.  This code merely clarifies the process.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to :

1. Extract all values with an 'a' in them and note their positions.
2. Sort the values alphabetically (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032521/python-data-structure-sort-list-alphabetically)).
3. Insert the sorted values into the original list.

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be simplified, but here's one way of doing it

```
def custom_sort(lst):
    sorted_list = [x for x in lst if 'a' in x] # get list of everything with an a in it
    sorted_list.sort() # sort this of elements containing a
    final_list = [] # make empty list, we will fill this with what we need
    sorted_counter = 0 # need a counter to keep track of what element containing a have been accounted for below
    for x in lst: # loop over original list
        if 'a' in x: # if that element in our original list contains an a
            final_list.append(sorted_list[sorted_counter]) # then we will from our sorted list of elements with a
            sorted_counter += 1 # increment counter
        else: # otherwise
            final_list.append(x) # we add an element from our original list
    return final_list # return the custom sorted list
```

Answer (score 0):

I just would use two additional lists to keep track of the indices of words with 'a' and to sorted the words:

```
L=['foo','bar','testa','python','java','abc']
M=[]
count=[]
for t in L:
    if 'a' in t:
        M.append(t)               #append both the word and the index
        count.append(L.index(t))
M=sorted(M)
for l in count:
    L[l]=M[count.index(l)]       
L
```

Probably is not very efficient but it works.