# List sorting except zero in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have a list `[5,3,0,0,4,1,4,0,7]`
and i want to sort the list in someway that zeros remain in their position and others be sorted the answer is like this `[1,3,0,0,4,4,5,0,7]`

i wrote this code but i cant fix the zeros in their place

```
def except_zero(items: list) -> Iterable: 
    ans=[] 
    for i in range(len(items)): 
        if (items[i] != 0): 
            ans.append(items[i]) 
            ans = sorted(ans) 

    j = 0 
    for i in range(len(items)): 
        if (items[i] >= 0): 
            items[i] = ans[j] 
            j += 1 
            return ans
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list with certain values staying in constant positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382174/sort-a-list-with-certain-values-staying-in-constant-positions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
orig_list = [5,3,0,0,4,1,4,0,7]
result = sorted([i for i in orig_list if i!=0])
for inx, elem in enumerate(orig_list):
    if elem == 0:
        result.insert(inx, 0)
print(result)  # [1,3,0,0,4,4,5,0,7]
```

Firstly I sort nonzeros, then insert zero in `result` list in places where it appear in `orig_list`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
def sort_and_extract_non_zero_items(items: list) -> Iterable:
  return sorted([n for n in l if n != 0])

def replace_non_zero_items(original: list, non_zeroes: list) -> Iterable:
  return [non_zeroes.pop(0) if n != 0 else 0 for n in original]

non_zero_list = sort_and_extract_non_zero_items(items)

items = replace_non_zero_items(items, non_zero_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient approach that solves the problem in *O(n)* time complexity is to store the indices of zeroes in a set, sort the rest of the items, and then iterate an index over the length of the input list to output zeroes if the index is in the set, or the next item in the sorted list if not:

```
def except_zero(items):
    zeroes = {i for i, v in enumerate(items) if v == 0}
    others = iter(sorted(v for v in items if v != 0))
    return [0 if i in zeroes else next(others) for i in range(len(items))]
```

so that:

```
except_zero([5,3,0,0,4,1,4,0,7])
```

returns:

```
[1, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 0, 7]
```

Comment: This is absolutely not O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but seems to work:

```py
l_in = [5,3,0,0,4,1,4,0,7]
l_out = []

# grab and sort all your non-zero values
nonz = sorted([x for x in l_in if x!=0])

# build your new list, adding a zero if there was one in that
# position, else poppping off the first item in the sorted
# non-zero list
for i in range(len(l_in)):
    l_out.append(0 if l_in[i]==0 else nonz.pop(0))

print(l_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def except_zero(items: list) -> Iterable: 
    ans=[]
    ind=[]
    for i in range(len(items)): 
        if (items[i] != 0): 
            ans.append(items[i]) 
            ind.append(i)

    ans = list(sorted(ans))
    for i in range(len(ind)): 
            items[ind[i]] = ans[i] 
    return items
```

Something  like the above would work, you simply store the index positions of non-zero values and then placve the sorted values into the corresponding index positions

Even your own approach can work if you fix a couple of issues, for example:

```
def except_zero(items: list) -> Iterable: 
    # get and sort non zero values
    non_zero = list(sorted([x for x in items if x!=0]))
    j = 0 
    # place them in correct position
    for i in range(len(items)): 
        if (items[i] != 0): 
            items[i] = non_zero[j]  # get next sorted non_zero value for this position
            j += 1 # update index

    return items
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first save the index position of zero values:

```
zero_positions = [i for i, this in enum(mylist) if this == 0]
```

then you could sort the list without the zero values:

```
ordered = [this for this in mylist if this != 0].sorted()
```

and finally you could insert zeros in the correct positions:

```
for i in zero_positions:
    ordered.insert(i, 0)
```

That's all. Maybe there is a faster way, this is the first that came to my mind.

Hope that helps
Francesco

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise, elegant and fast way to do it.

```py
def except_zero(items):
    nonzero = iter(sorted(filter(bool, items)))
    return [i and next(nonzero) for i in items]
```

##### How does it compare?

For all these tests, I used a list with a million elements, of which 10% were each integer from 0 to 9, running on Python 3.11.4.

It's **2837x faster** than [Mr Felix U's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500075/16435355).

It's **2805x faster** than [Onilol's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500085/16435355).

It's **109x faster** than [FAL's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500372/16435355).

It's **108x faster** than [Daweo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500096/16435355) (the accepted answer).

It's **39% faster** than [blhsing's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500350/16435355).

It's **34% faster** than [Nikos M's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500093/16435355).

[Prasad Shembekar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111305/16435355) doesn't work.

##### How does it work?

The `filter` takes advantage of the fact that, for `float` and `int`, the only value that will return `False` when passed to `bool` is `0` - so all other values will be `True`. This gives us our nonzero values, which we then sort (with `sorted`) and convert to an iterable (with `iter`) so that we can use `next` on it.

The list comprehension utilises a short-circuit - if `i` is `0`, the `and` short-circuits, returning the last evaluated value (`0`). This has the effect of placing the zeroes in their original positions. The `next` fills in the spaces which weren't zeroes with the sorted values, which we generated earlier.

Comment: Where did you get the absurd 2837x times faster from? I actually timed this (with random lists) and your solution is only around 2 to 2.5 times faster rather than 2837x... I didn't test the other ones but I highly doubt most of your benchmarking here.

Answer (score 0):

this solution might help you

```
my_list = [3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 4]

# Sort the list, excluding zeros
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x == 0, x))

print(sorted_list)
```