# Replace values by order of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
keywords = ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
```

```
df.column
0   The Small, Large, Medium
1   The fast Medium, Small XS
2   He was a Medium, Large or Small
```

How could I tell pandas if a row contains a keyword:

1. Replace the keywords so that the keywords appear in the order of the list
2. If the keyword contains a suffix, "XS", include that with step 1

Expected Output:

```
0 The Small, Medium, Large 
1 The fast Small XS, Medium
2 He was a Small, Medium or Large
```

Comment: Is `XS` the only valid suffix? If not, how do you know that `or` in row 2 is not a suffix for `Medium`?

Comment: yep ```XS``` is the only valid suffix

Comment: Can there be duplicates of each keyword or only one of each e.g.  are `Medium, Medium` or `Small, Small XS` valid?

Comment: There won't be duplicates in my case, but I guess the more general solution the better,  if possible

Comment: do you have an order between Small and Small XS, or want to preserve the order as they appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to:

1. Split the string into words which match the keywords (with or without the `XS` suffix), or other non-matching parts using `re.findall`
2. Sort the words which match according to their index in the keywords list
3. Rebuild the words list using the sorted keywords
4. Join the string back together

You can do that with this function:

```py
def sizesorter(s, keywords):
    words = re.findall(r'((?:\b(?:' + '|'.join(keywords) + r')\b)(?:\sXS)?|(?:[^\s]*(?:\s|$)))', s, re.I)
    sizes = iter(sorted([w for w in words if w.split(' ')[0] in keywords], key=lambda w:keywords.index(w.split(' ')[0])))
    words = [w if w.split(' ')[0] not in keywords else next(sizes) for w in words]
    return ''.join(words)
```

You can then apply that function to the column. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'column' : ['The Small, Large, Medium',
'The fast Medium, Small XS',
'He was a Medium, Large or Small',
'small, Large a metre'
] })

def sizesorter(s, keywords):
    words = re.findall(r'((?:\b(?:' + '|'.join(keywords) + r')\b)(?:\sXS)?|(?:[^\s]*(?:\s|$)))', s, re.I)
    sizes = iter(sorted([w for w in words if w.split(' ')[0] in keywords], key=lambda w:keywords.index(w.split(' ')[0])))
    words = [w if w.split(' ')[0] not in keywords else next(sizes) for w in words]
    return ''.join(words)
    
df.column = df.column.apply(sizesorter, args=(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], ))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                            column
0         The Small, Medium, Large
1        The fast Small XS, Medium
2  He was a Small, Medium or Large
```

Partial sorting of the list of words adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45382297/9473764).

Comment: Many many thanks! I didn't want to overcomplicate the question. If a row also has a prefix, "Size", would it be easy to amend the code so that Size is always at the front: ie change ```The Large, Size Medium, Small``` to ```The Size Small, Medium, Large ```

Comment: @asd I'm glad this worked for you. It's late here - I'll sleep on the problem but you might get a quicker response with a new question, you can refer back to this one for context. Off the top of my head I thought adding `Size` to the keyword list might work but it's not quite right https://ideone.com/wUGJFR

Comment: Thanks no problem if not! Would you also know why the end of a sentence is sometimes chopped off, for both rows that contain and even rows that don't contain a keyword. For example "metre" in "small, large a metre" is being deleted

Comment: @asd quick fix for the word deletion issue, I didn't allow for a non-size word at the end of the string, change the pattern to `r'((?:' + '|'.join(keywords) + ')(?:\sXS)?|(?:[^\s]*(?:\s|$)))'`. Still thinking about how best to resolve the `Size` issue. Got some ideas but real work is in the way... :P

Comment: @asd haven't had a lot of time to look at this, but here's something that does work, if not the most efficient: https://ideone.com/fUy1a7

Comment: Many thanks, unfortunately I'm getting list index out of range for the sizes[0] line

Comment: @asd all the code is case sensitive, that is likely causing that problem. You will need to convert case before comparison (perhaps make keywords all lowercase and translate each word as well before comparison)

Comment: @asd I think this does what you want (and is case insensitive). It's a bit ugly but I unfortunately don't have the time to look at it any more... https://ideone.com/fbvaIq