# Alphabetical names in Django list

Tags: django

I want to Display my List name in alphabetical order {{ name }}

```
Philip
Bosson
Alivio
```

i.e I want to make it like

```
Alivio
Bosson
Philip
```

Help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sorted command to generate the list.

```
sorted(["Philip","Bosson","Alivio"])
```

You probably want to do this in the view then pass it in the context down to the html template.

More details with this post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032521/python-data-structure-sort-list-alphabetically)

Then in django template

```
{% for name in sorted_list %} {{name}} {%endfor %}
```