# how do i sort arabic list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, arabic

on python3 , i want to sort a list of arabic words IN THE ALPHABETIC ORDER the file i have has this content

```
حصل,شد
حصن,حضا
حضر,جا
حض,أكد
حضن,تهلا
حطب,حطب
حطم,هرس
```

and i want to sort it by the first column so the output become

```
حض,أكد
حصن,حضا
حطب,حطب
حضن,تهلا
حضر,جا
حصل,شد
حطم,هرس
```

i tried using the function sort it didn't work i think i m missing something

my code is something like that

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv
import sort
d=[]
with open('sort.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8' , newline='\n') as in_fp:
    with open('result.csv','w', encoding='utf-8' , newline='\n') as out_fp:
        for row in (csv.reader(in_fp, delimiter=',')):
            d.append=row[1]
        d.sort()
```

and then i want to save it in the `result.csv`

i found this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032521/python-data-structure-sort-list-alphabetically)! but i don't it is working for me

Comment: Can you include some code you have written? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: In what way do `sort`/`sorted` not work? Is the result wrong, or is there an exception, or something else?

Comment: i have added some code above, the problem is that i don't know how to code this phrase " i want to sort based on the second column the elements of the file"

Comment: i used the list d because i earlier used this line but it didn't work  : 
   csv.writer(out_fp).writerows((csv.reader(in_fp, delimiter=',').row[1]).sort())

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings)