# How to have Python dictionary sorted with opposite sort direction of groups inside of it, and do it in an elegant way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data in the dictionary and want to get it in another dictionary but inserted/sorted in the following way:

- the items sorted in a descending way for keys the first letter:

  'z':1, ...., 'a':1
- but inside of groups of items, which have the same first letter, to have opposite sort direction:

  'aaa':1, 'abb':1, 'acc':1, ....

Here I have my example of code for this task(sorted by key), it works but I am looking for something more elegant:

```
    my_dict = {
        'abc': 'aaaa',
        'bus': 'bbba',
        'apple': 'abbb',
        'banana': 'bbaa',
        'angel': 'aabb',
        'baseball': 'baaa',
    }

    starting_letters = reversed(sorted({k[0] for k in my_dict.keys()}))
    result = {}

    for i in starting_letters:
        intermediate = {}
        for k in my_dict.keys():
            if k.startswith(i):
                intermediate[k] = my_dict[k]
        result.update(dict(sorted(intermediate.items())))

    print(result)
```

this is the output:

{'banana': 'bbaa', 'baseball': 'baaa', 'bus': 'bbba', 'abc': 'aaaa', 'angel': 'aabb', 'apple': 'abbb'}

as you can see it's sorted descending:
  (items with key starting on b goes before items with key starting on a)
but groups of items are sorted ascending:

'banana': 'bbaa', 'baseball': 'baaa', 'bus': 'bbba'

'abc': 'aaaa', 'angel': 'aabb', 'apple': 'abbb'

Comment: Are you asking about reversed alphabetical sorting?

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python data structure sort list alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032521/python-data-structure-sort-list-alphabetically)

Comment: A Python `dict` is an unordered data structure by definition. There is no way to "sort" a dict.

Comment: I've edited the question, please check last part where I try to explain it

Comment: @Tomalak Incorrect - dicts preserve insertion order since Python 3.7.

Comment: I have data in 'my_dict' inserted/sorted one way and want to get another dictionary(named 'result' in my question) with the same data inserted/sorted in the way mentioned in the question, How to get it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karl Knechtel's suggestion has very good answers but I didn't find there exactly what I was looking for, so I have my own  answer:

```
dict(
    sorted(
        sorted(my_dict.items()), 
        key=lambda x: x[0][0], 
        reverse=True
    )
)
```