# Nested list with python basic

Tags: python

Given the names and grades for each student in a class of N students,
store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s)
having the second lowest grade.

Note: If there are multiple students with the second lowest grade,
order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

Example

```
 reords = [['chi', 20.0], ['bela', 50.0], ['alpha', 50.0]]
```

The ordered list of scores is [20.0, 50.0], so the second lowest score
is 50.0 There are two students with that score:['beta', 'alpha'] .
Ordered alphabetically, the names are printed as:

Input format:

The first line contains an integer, N, the number of students. The 2N
subsequent lines describe each student over 2 lines.

- The first line contains a student's name.
- The second line contains their grade.

Output Format

Print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade in.
If there are multiple students, order their names alphabetically and
print each one on a new line.

Example of input: Sample Input 0

```
 5
 Harry
 37.21
 Berry
 37.21
 Tina
 37.2
 Akriti
 41
 Harsh
 39
```

Sample Output 0

```
 Berry
 Harry
```

This my proposition code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    student = []
    values = []
    names =[]
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        student.append([name, score])

    for item in student:
        values.append(item[1])
    values=list(set(values))
    values.sort()

    for item in student:
        if item[1] == values[1]:
            names.append(item[0])
    names.sort()

    for name in names:
        print(name)
```

when I run the code on jupiter Notebook I have the same resume. But when I run the same code in the éditor of the test I have an error. I don't understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyFxx.png)

Comment: I am pretty sure a verry similar quesiton was already asked here

Comment: The error is saying there are certain inputs that your code doesn't work with. Test it with the full input in your screenshot and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know, but I want to have more explanation to this problem. please look the image to see what I want to talk about

Comment: Thank's, Peter. let me see and run again

Comment: Possible [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032628/11177720)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is:

- Add all students with their marks to list `reords`
- Sort list with unique marks (using `set`)
- Filter list to get a student with the second min mark
- Print name for each filtered student

Tested [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    reords = []
    
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        reords.append([name, score])
 
    mark = sorted(set(map(lambda x: x[1], reords)))[1]
    for n, m in sorted(filter(lambda x: x[1] == mark, reords)):
        print(n)
```

Comment: You can test your code here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem

Comment: can you publish your code please, juste to see?

Comment: @AmounguiSerge, you can see it in my answer :) However, https://pastebin.com/fVa5zb2x

Comment: Cool, your code code work correctly. that's right. thank's for your help.

Comment: I find you very experienced, how to stay in contact in order to exchange regularly. because I like your way of code, I would like to reach this level

Answer (score 0):

```
student = []
marks = []
names = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    student.append([name, score])

for item in student:
    marks.append(item[1])
marks = list(set(marks))
marks.sort()

for item in student:
    if marks[1] == item[1]:
        names.append(item[0])
names.sort()

for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Hi Abhilash, thanks for contributing an answer. It's good practice to include a brief explanation of your code in your answer so that future readers can quickly understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

```
nested_list=[]
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    nested_list+=[[score, name]]
nested_list.sort()

for i in nested_list:
    if i[0]>nested_list[0][0]:
        second_lowest_grade= i[0]
        break;

student_names=[i[1] for i in nested_list if i[0]==second_lowest_grade]
student_names.sort()
for student_name in student_names:
    print(student_name)
```